# Outlook mail "Array index is out of bounds"

Tags: excel, vba

I have the problem with Outlook mail. I'm creating the HTML mail via Excel VBA and it's displaying properly. When a user click "Send", it's sending properly. But if user (on Outlook 2016) try to add an attachment, gets the prompt "Array index is out of bounds" (even, if Excel is closed after creating mail), so I think it's Outlook's problem rather than Excel's. It's not happening on Outlook 2010.

I've noticed, that when user change message type to RTF, then it's possible to add an attachment (but HTML formatting is quite important for me, because I want to send a table in body).

I've searched Stack and other sites, but everything I've found on that prompt was occuring in Excel while code was running. Thanks in advance :)

---

I was asked for the code (it's not important in my opinion, but maybe i'm wrong ;) ).

```
Sub WysyłanieMaila(Treść As String, Temat As String, Adresat As String, DW As String, Załącznik As String)

Dim Wyświetlanie As Boolean
Dim Wyślij As Boolean
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Wyświetlanie = True
Wyślij = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .BodyFormat = 3
    If Wyświetlanie Then .Display
    .To = Adresat 
    .CC = DW
    .Subject = Temat
    .Body = Treść
    .Attachments.Add Załącznik
    If Wyślij Then
        .Send
    Else
        .Display
    End If
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function TreśćHTMLDoMaila(WierszMin As Long, WierszMax As Long) As String

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim KolumnaPoczątek As Integer
Dim KolumnaKoniec As Integer

KolumnaPoczątek = 1
KolumnaKoniec = 18

TreśćHTMLDoMaila = "<table border=1 cellpadding=5 style=""border-collapse:collapse""><tr>"

For j = KolumnaPoczątek To KolumnaKoniec
    If Not j = 4 And Not j = 14 And Not j = 15 And Not j = 17 Then TreśćHTMLDoMaila = TreśćHTMLDoMaila & "<td><b><font face=""Calibri"" size=""2"">" & Arkusz1.Cells(1, j).Value & "</font></b></td>"
Next j
TreśćHTMLDoMaila = TreśćHTMLDoMaila & "</tr>"

For i = WierszMin To WierszMax
    If Arkusz1.Cells(i, 25).Value = "Nierozliczone" Then
        TreśćHTMLDoMaila = TreśćHTMLDoMaila & "<tr>"
        For j = KolumnaPoczątek To KolumnaKoniec
            If Not j = 4 And Not j = 14 And Not j = 15 And Not j = 17 Then TreśćHTMLDoMaila = TreśćHTMLDoMaila & "<td><font face=""Calibri"" size=""2"">" & Arkusz1.Cells(i, j).Value & "</font></td>"
        Next j
        TreśćHTMLDoMaila = TreśćHTMLDoMaila & "</tr>"
    End If
Next i

TreśćHTMLDoMaila = TreśćHTMLDoMaila & "</table>"

End Function
```

Comment: Which line of code gives an exception? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: No line. The error occurs in Outlook, not in Excel code. I've told that in post - it displays properly, it sends properly, but doesn't add an attachment properly.

Comment: What is the actual value passed to the `Attachments.Add` method?

Comment: You are using `On Error Resume Next` incorrectly. Remove that line and you will likely see an error, possibly related to the attachment. Even if you do not see an error, do not use it again before reading this. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: Seems like passing an empty string ("") to Attachment.Add was causing error in Outlook 2016, but not in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find which line of code gives an error by running the code under the debugger. See [Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) for more information. But I think the problem lies in the `TreśćHTMLDoMaila` function.

The [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method creates a new attachment in the `Attachments` collection. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. So, you just need to make sure the file path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it wasn't the case (as I mentioned earlier, there was no problem when code running), but deleting the line with .Attachment.Add solved the problem on my computer. I've asked my coworkers, waiting for response.